# foreach and current

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
foreach ($a as $key => $elem) {
    echo "$key = $elem"; echo ' = ';
    var_dump(current($a));\
}
?>
```

The output I get when running that is as follows:

```
0 = 1 = int(2)

1 = 2 = int(2)

2 = 3 = int(2)

3 = 4 = int(2)

4 = 5 = int(2)
```

Seems to me that this is the output I should be getting?:

```
0 = 1 = int(1)

1 = 2 = int(2)

2 = 3 = int(3)

3 = 4 = int(4)

4 = 5 = int(5)
```

I do current() before the for loop on $a and get int(1). Thus it seems like it's the foreach loop that's causing it to increment. But if that's the case why is it only doing it once?

If I call next() in the for loop it increments but not otherwise. Of course next() starts out at int(3) (ie. the value after int(2))..

Comment: Why are you var_dumping it?

Comment: Because I was initially doing next() and that was returning bool(false). I did var_dump() to distinguish between int(0) and bool(false).

Comment: Why is current=2 in this example? Before running foreach, current=1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works for a full explanation of this.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the PHP documention on current, it does not look like you should expect foreach to move the current pointer.

Please see:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

What's a bit confusing is that the each function does move the current pointer.  So if you rewrite your array as a loop using each rather than foreach, then you will get the desired current behavior.

Here's your example rewritten with each(), which produces the expected results:

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
while ( list($key,$elem) = each($a)) {
    echo "$key = $elem"; echo ' = ';
    var_dump(current($a));
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah - that's what's confusing me - the fact that foreach does seem to be incrementing the pointer but only once.  Seems to me that it should increment it every time or not at all.

Answer (score 0):

`current()` uses the internal flag (pointer) and foreach uses it's own.

If you want to do this (which is kind of silly as you have the key in $key) you can use [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/ArrayIterator)

Comment: Why, then, is current() saying int(2) instead of int(1) the whole time? As for why I'm doing current()... I believe it better illustrates the unexpected way the internal flag is behaving than next() or prev() does.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on the same problem, and I believe I have a theory.
Foreach doesn't access the array elements by value, it creates its own copy. However, while doing this, it increments the value returned by current() just once.

To check this:

```
<?php

$a = [0, 1, 2];
    foreach ($a as &$val){ // accessing the array elts by reference this time
    var_dump(current($a));
}

/*this outputs:
int(1)
int(2)
bool(false)*/
```